# Issue about main and second GitHub account with SSH connection in Windows 10

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have a main account for my personal projects: personal@gmail.com and connect to it with HTTPS (default connection).
I've been added another Gmail (work@gmail.com) and generated **work** and **work.pub** keys, added the public key content to the work GitHub account. With the related configuration and changing the username and email from git config file, everything is fine and works well .

I want to define a configuration for all projects to have SSH connection to the **work@gmail**  at path C:\Projects\Work.

I have these config files:

At path **C:\Users\MyUser\.ssh\config**

```
# Main GitHub
Host main
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/main-github
    IdentitiesOnly yes

# Work GitHub
Host work
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_github
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

At path **C:\Users\MyUser\.ssh.gitconfig**

```
[filter "lfs"]
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
[user]
    name = personal
    email = personal@gmail.com
[includeIf "gitdir:C:/Projects/Work/"]
    path = C:/Projects/work/.gitconfig
[core]
    editor = \"C:\\Users\\MyUser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" --wait
    sshCommand = C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
```

At path **C:\Projects\Work.gitconfig**

```
[user]
    name = work
    email = work@gmail.com
[core]
    sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/work_github"
```

And then I generated **personal** and **personal.pub** keys, and add the public key to the main GitHub account (personal@gmail.com), to have a SSH connection for it.

With command `ssh -Tv main` :

```
Hi main! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2192, received 2608 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3664.8, received 4360.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

With command `ssh -Tv work` :

```
Hi work! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2192, received 2608 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3664.8, received 4360.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

The Problem:

❌ I can't connect to the work GitHub with SSH:

```
ERROR: Permission to work/project.git denied to personal.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

✅ I can connect to the main account with SSH.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since `ssh -Tv work` works, it means that SSH to your work account works just fine. What exactly is giving you the error?

Comment: I solved this problem with just deleting the personal key from `ssh-add` with this command `ssh-add -d ~/.ssh/personal`. By the way, `ssh-add` in git bash is different from ssh-add in vscode , because they showed me different ssh-agent.